# Exception thrown by Visual Studio regarding TextBox object

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

**Error:**

> No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to a known managed provider native type

I have no idea why is my Visual Studio throwing me this type of error, any sugestions?

**Code Snippet :**

```
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
            cc.con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            cc.con.Open();
            string cb = "insert into Product(P_ID,ProductID,ProductName,SubCategoryID,Features,Price,VAT,ST,Discount,Photo) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10)";
            cc.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
            cc.cmd.Connection = cc.con;
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", txtID.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", txtProductID);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", txtProductName.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", txtSubCategoryID.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", txtFeatures.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6", txtPrice.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", txtVAT.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d8", txtServiceTax.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d9", txtDiscount.Text);
            cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d10",data);
            cc.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cc.con.Close();
            st1 = lblUser.Text;
            st2 = "adicionou um produto '" + txtProductName.Text + "'";
            cf.LogFunc(st1,System.DateTime.Now,st2);
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @Sparrow I think it's about the productID not being associated with a .Text event, so yeah, I'm going to check it out and give feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", txtProductID);` to `cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", txtProductID.Text);`